# count items across all columns using pandas method

Tags: scikit-learn, countvectorizer

I have this dataframe and I can get the count of each item per row using vectorizer. But this works correctly for single row (for e.g. col1). How do I apply it to entire dataframe (all 3 columns)?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

shopping_list = [
    ["Apple", "Bread", "Fridge"],
    ["Rice", "Bread", "Milk"],
    ["Apple", "Rice", "Bread"],
    ["Rice", "Milk", "Milk"],
    ["Apple", "Bread", "Milk"],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(shopping_list)
df.columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']

CV = CountVectorizer()
cv_matrix=CV.fit_transform(df['col1'].values)
ndf = pd.SparseDataFrame(cv_matrix)
ndf.columns = CV.get_feature_names()
X = ndf.fillna("0")
```

The results are correct for single column:

```
apple   rice
0   1   0
1   0   1
2   1   0
3   0   1
4   1   0
```

Expected Results for all columns:

```
    Apple   Rice    Bread   Milk    Fridge
0   1   0   1   0   1
1   0   1   1   1   0
2   1   1   1   0   0
3   0   1   0   2   0
4   1   0   1   1   0
```

Is there any other way to get the same results?

Comment: Hi @shantanuo did the answer help you??

Comment: Can you tell me you why `python` tag is not relevant for this question?

Comment: If you are counting the items, then milk has to be 2 in 4th row right?

Comment: Removed python tag because I am looking for a solution using "CountVectorizer" class only. ALollz has already answered this question. He could use sum instead of max to get milk 2 in row 4

Comment: Does your real data look similar to this? You might be better of using a different data structure? I believe it’s been brought up already, but I will also encourage replacing that SparseDataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stack and get dummies. Then take the max by index (`sum` if you want counts instead of dummies)

```
pd.get_dummies(df.stack()).max(level=0)

   Apple  Bread  Fridge  Milk  Rice
0      1      1       1     0     0
1      0      1       0     1     1
2      1      1       0     0     1
3      0      0       0     1     1
4      1      1       0     1     0
```

Alternatively, `get_dummies` on the entire DataFrame with blank prefixes and group along the columns axis.

```
pd.get_dummies(df, prefix='', prefix_sep='').max(level=0, axis=1)
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the same results using count vectorizer?

Comment: @shantanuo perhaps, but is there any reason not to use that simple <40 character piece of code that gets you exactly where you need to be? As a warning `pd.SparseDataFrame` is deprecated so I'd avoid relying on it, might be better to switch to `pd.DataFrame(cv_matrix.toarray())`

Comment: This step is part of complex script that uses sklearn module extensively. Therefore I prefer count vectorizer over generic pandas method. If it is too complex, I will use get_dummies!

Comment: Fair, I'm not too familiar with using that, someone else with more knowledge will hopefully answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate column by joining all the existing columns and apply `CountVectorizer` on it. Please refer to the sample code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

shopping_list = [
    ["Apple", "Bread", "Fridge"],
    ["Rice", "Bread", "Milk"],
    ["Apple", "Rice", "Bread"],
    ["Rice", "Milk", "Milk"],
    ["Red Chillies", "Bread", "Milk"],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(shopping_list)
df.columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
vocab = set(df.values.flatten())
v = [i.lower() for i in vocab]
df['new'] = df.apply(' '.join, axis=1)
```

So your new dataframe will look like this

```
    col1           col2     col3    new
0   Apple          Bread    Fridge  Apple Bread Fridge
1   Rice           Bread    Milk    Rice Bread Milk
2   Apple          Rice     Bread   Apple Rice Bread
3   Rice           Milk     Milk    Rice Milk Milk
4   Red Chillies   Bread    Milk    Red Chillies Bread Milk
```

Now you can apply `CountVectorizer` on the new column as shown below:

```
CV = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=vocab, , ngram_range=(1,5))
cv_matrix=CV.fit_transform(df.new)
```

And you can get your desired dataframe using:

```
pd.DataFrame(cv_matrix.toarray(), columns= CV.get_feature_names())

    bread   milk    fridge  rice    apple   red chillies
0   1       0       1       0       1       0
1   1       1       0       1       0       0
2   1       0       0       1       1       0
3   0       2       0       1       0       0
4   1       1       0       0       0       1
```

Comment: Instead of "Apple" if I have "Red chillies", those words are not kept together in the report dataframe :(

Comment: In that case you could create your own vocabulary from the list of words you have and pass it to the `CountVectorizer`, also just make sure that when you specify `ngram_range` the max value it more than the longest word you could expect, here I have set it as 5.

Answer (score 1):

If you find creating a new column combining all the individual columns as an overhead, you can use generators, which can let you fit large data.

Also, the recommended way of reading sparse matrix in pandas dataframe is `sparse.from_spmatrix`. Read more [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/sparse.html#migrating)

```
cv = CountVectorizer()
pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(cv.fit_transform(
    ' '.join(x) for x in shopping_list),
    columns=cv.get_feature_names())
```

[image]

If you need to apply `CountVectorizer` in Dataframe, then use

```
' '.join(x[1:]) for x in df.itertuples()
```

Comment: `.iterrows()` has some pretty important drawbacks, I would recommend using `.itertuples()` instead.

Comment: Thanks fr the suggestion. I would incorporate it.